# Script won't log in

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I know I'm missing something here. I've been staring at this short script for a while now and I can't see where it's going wrong.
Here's my script:

http://pastebin.com/FtNeNtwj

And here's the script in action:

http://troop007.tk/login.007?action=login

The username and password are both "demo". I type in the username and password, press log in, and instead of taking me to login.007?action=logincheck, it never leaves login.007?action=login.

I have one MySQL table called users, and inside that table there are two fields: username and password.

The script I'm using is a modified version of the script found here: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Comment: You should not store plain text passwords in your db or use the old mysql_* functions.

Comment: i just tried it and when entering those credentials it redirects me to a page not found by the server, throwing a 404. which is the same as when you manually enter ´login.007?action=success"´ in the address bar. are you sure its not working?

Comment: @jere I'm pretty sure. I didn't get any 404s when manually typing in ?action=success or logging in normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would scrap that tutorial, login security is not tobe looked upon lightly, you should not have plaintext passwords in the database they should be hashed with a salt and both should change upon successful login.

**Here is A secure login script:**

It uses PDO for the database connection, the actual login form uses random keys for login eg. not username/password. Passwords are hashed with sha512 x 25k times and with a 16byte key salt, brute force protection. Hope it helps.

```
<?php
session_start();

/**
 * Table

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass_hash` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass_salt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;

 */

//DB Stuff
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBNAME','yourdb');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');
//End Config:---


//Open a PDO Database connection
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch (Exception $e){
    die('Cannot connect to mySQL server.');
}


class Login{
    public $db;
    public $user;
    public $pass;
    public $error;
    // sha512
    public $algo = '$6';
    // Cost parameter, 25k iterations
    public $cost = '$rounds=25000$';

    function __construct(PDO $db){
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->global_salt = sha1($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    }

    /**
     * Return a random seed for the mt_rand function
     */
    function make_seed(){
        list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
        return (float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 100000);
    }

    /**
     * Return a random unique salt for new created hash/crypt function salts
     */
    function unique_salt(){
        $salt = null;
        mt_srand($this->make_seed());
        for($i=0;$i < mt_rand(1,10);$i++){
            $salt = sha1($this->global_salt.$salt.mt_rand().uniqid().microtime(true));
        }
        return substr($salt,0,16);
    }

    /**
     * Hash a given password and store parts in:
     * $this->salt = a unique 16 byte salt
     * $this->hash = The full crypted hash sting including algo/cost/salt/crytedpassword
     * $this->full_salt = Just algo/cost/salt section, the first 33 bytes 
     * $this->hashed_password = Just crytedpassword section, proceeding bytes after first 33 bytes
     * 
     */
    function hash($password){
        $this->salt = $this->unique_salt();
        $this->full_hash = crypt($password, $this->algo.$this->cost.$this->salt);
        $this->full_salt = substr($this->full_hash, 0, 33);
        $this->hashed_password = substr($this->full_hash, 33);
        return $this->full_hash;
    }

    /**
     * Method to validate the given crypto hash against the given password
     */
    function check_password($hash, $salt, $password){
        $hash = ($this->algo.$this->cost.$salt.'$'.$hash);
        if($hash == crypt($password, substr($hash, 0, 33))){
            //Regenerate new hash and salt for given password
            $this->update_keys();
            $this->status = true;
            $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->status = false;
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set error
     */
    function set_error($type,$value){
        $this->error[$type]=$value;
    }

    /**
     * Output error
     */
    function error($type){
        echo (isset($this->error[$type]))?$this->error[$type]:null;
    }

    /**
     * Logout and regenirate session and redirect to index
     */
    static function logout(){
        unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        exit(header('Location: ./index.php'));
    }

    function anti_brute($intval){
        if(!isset($_SESSION['access_time'])){
            $_SESSION['access_time']=time();
        }else{
            $t = time()-$_SESSION['access_time'];
            if($t <= $intval){
                $this->set_error('global','Time violation');
                $_SESSION['access_time']=time();
                return true;
            }
            $_SESSION['access_time']=time();
            return false;
        }
    }

    function process_login(){
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

            $this->user   = (isset($_SESSION['userParam']) && isset($_POST[$_SESSION['userParam']]))?$_POST[$_SESSION['userParam']]:null;
            $this->pass   = (isset($_SESSION['passParam']) && isset($_POST[$_SESSION['passParam']]))?$_POST[$_SESSION['passParam']]:null;
            $this->create = (isset($_SESSION['createParam']) && isset($_POST[$_SESSION['createParam']]))?$_POST[$_SESSION['createParam']]:null;

            $cont = true;
            if($this->user == null || strlen($this->user) <= 2){$this->set_error('user','Please enter a username!'); $cont=false;}
            if($this->pass == null || strlen($this->pass) <= 2){$this->set_error('pass','Please enter a password!'); $cont=false;}


            if($cont==true){
                //Alls good continue
                if($this->create != null && $this->create=='1'){
                    //Check user for new account
                    if($this->check_user()==true){$this->set_error('user','Username already taken.');return;}
                    //Create account
                    $this->create_account();
                }else{
                    //Stop really fast request 2 seconds
                    if($this->anti_brute(2)==false){
                        //Attempt to login
                        $this->check_login();
                    }
                }
            }else{
                //Error with form
                $this->set_error('global','Please fill in login form!');
            }
        }
    }

    function check_user(){
        $sql = 'SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username=:username';
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $this->user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!empty($result)){return true;}else{return false;}
    }

    function check_login(){
        $sql = 'SELECT pass_hash, pass_salt FROM users WHERE username=:username';
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $this->user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $this->check_password($result['pass_hash'], $result['pass_salt'], $this->pass);
    }

    function create_account(){
        //Create new account
        $this->hash($this->pass);
        $sql = 'INSERT into users (username, pass_hash, pass_salt) VALUES (:username, :pass_hash, :pass_salt)';
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $this->user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':pass_hash', $this->hashed_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':pass_salt', $this->salt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();

        $this->status = true;
        $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
    }

    function update_keys(){
        //Update account password hash & salt
        $this->hash($this->pass);
        $sql = 'UPDATE users SET pass_hash=:pass_hash, pass_salt=:pass_salt WHERE username=:username';
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $this->user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':pass_hash', $this->hashed_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':pass_salt', $this->salt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();

        $this->status = true;
        $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
    }

}//END Login class

//Logout handler
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){ Login::logout(); }

$login = new Login($db);

//Login handler
$login->process_login();

//Debug
echo '<pre>';
print_r($login);
echo '</pre>';


//Check login status
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']==true){
    //Logged in
    echo '<a href="?logout">Logout</a>';
}else{
    //Not Logged In

    //Show login form & create uniqie parrams for user/pass/create post keys
    $_SESSION['userParam']   = sha1(uniqid().microtime(true));
    $_SESSION['passParam']   = sha1(uniqid().microtime(true));
    $_SESSION['createParam'] = sha1(uniqid().microtime(true));
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Secure Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Secure Login Example</h1>
<h3>Please login:</h3>

<?php $login->error('global'); ?>

<form method="POST" action="">
  <label for="user">Username :&nbsp; </label>
  <input type="text" name="<?=$_SESSION['userParam'];?>" size="29"> <?php $login->error('user'); ?>
  <br />
  <label for="pass">Password :&nbsp; </label>
  <input type="text" name="<?=$_SESSION['passParam'];?>" size="29"> <?php $login->error('pass'); ?>
  <br /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Login">&nbsp; and create my account:<input type="checkbox" name="<?=$_SESSION['createParam'];?>" value="1">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i think this is great, and definitely the best approach, but waaaaaaaay out of the scope of what the OP is talking about

Comment: @jere it might be out of scope, but hte OP is using so many bad practices left right and center that the answer of 'you're doing everything wrong' is appropriate.  Mind you, there are some things here I'd never even though of doing myself -- scrambling the names for username / password?  Wow, paranoid...  I'm surprised you don't use javascript to encrypt the actual data!

Comment: I just put it out there, these badly written tuts should get taken down. To many sites get hacked nowadays.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Well, thanks for putting it up.  There are a few things in there that *I* could stand to learn from (and I thought I was doing pretty good with salted and hashed passwords!).  Just out of curiosity, *why* randomize the form's name attributes?  Doesn't SSL secure that anyway (and if you aren't using SSL, you've got a whole slew of other issues anyway)?

Comment: Im thinking bots and brute forcers, the keys are generated on each refresh and the old ones are stale so a bot would need hold session scrape the page and then do the request instead of knowing which keys are which, just another level to annoy some script kiddy.. ssl is a must as it secures the connection between client and host stopping man in the middle attacks.

Comment: Dang, that's gotta be the most secure script I've seen, but does anyone know why the crappy one I have isn't working?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out myself. I was staring at it and I missed it. Since this is the most secure script I've ever seen you get a cookie and an accepted answer.

Comment: How can the enc value be decrypted, assuming final salt value is known..? I guess this is a one-way process, and will need to brute-forced?

Comment: @sunshine yes password hashing is only one way.