# Unable to insert data into database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I've written this code for a registration page, but I am unable to get insert data into my database using PDO(or doing something incorrectly rather). Here is the registration page code:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST)){

?>
 <form name="registration" action="register.php" method="POST">
<label for "username">Username: </label>
<input type="text" name="username"/><br />
<label for "password">Password: </label>
<input type="password" name="password"/><br />
<label for "fname">First Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="fname"/><br />
<label for "lname">Last name: </label> 
<input type="text" name="lname"/><br />
<label for "email">Email: </label>
<input type="text" name="email"/><br />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php 
}
else{
    $form = $_POST;
    $username = $form['username'];
    $password = $form['passowrd'];
    $fname = $form['fname'];
    $lname = $form['lname'];
    $email = $form['email'];
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'pdt1848!';

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phpproject', $user, $pass);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, fname, lname, email)VALUES(:username, :password, :fname, :lname, :email)";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result = $query->execute(array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password, 
            ':fname'=>$fname, ':lname'=>$lname, ':email'=>$email));

    if ($result){
        echo "Thanks for registering with us!";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, an error occurred while editing the database. Contact the guy who built this garbage.";
    };

};
?>
```

Comment: place this at the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` what errors do you see ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It does not matter if `;` is there or not. Code will work in that way. Though, it is not needed there.

Comment: @Tuga under after <?php ? I put it there and nothing showed up.

Comment: Also, when I do enter in the information and click submit, it still says "Thanks for registering with us!" as if $result occurred.

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after `$db = new ...` and keep there the `error_reporting` which @Tuga suggested and tell us if anything showed up.

Comment: @user3566526 what Yoda says ;p

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment. This was due to my file not being saved as register.php it is now showing the error message like it should. Thanks to your advice @Tuga I figured it out. I mispelled 'password' as 'passowrd' -_- thanks for the assistance guys! No doubt I'll be back. Also thanks for the tip Yoda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is right here, `passowrd`

```
$password = $form['passowrd'];
```

A mere typo.

change it to:

```
$password = $form['password'];
```

when one fails, the whole query fails.

Had you error reporting in your code, it would've picked it up right away.

Ways that you can use in the future are a `try & catch` method, such as:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

as well as

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Links that you can consult for further reading:

PDO

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

MySQL

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://www.php.net/mysqli_error

(more)

- http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors
- http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you are storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

Comment: Yep! Thanks again for the quick responses

Comment: You're welcome @user3566526 Another happing ending ;-) Let's mark 'er off

Comment: No advice to the OP about using exceptions then, just pointing out a typo..

Answer (score 0):

Well I do something like this,

```
$user = 'your username';
$pass = 'your pass';
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_data_base_name', $user, $pass );
/*Grab Post*/
$form = $_POST;
$username = $form[ 'username' ];
$password = $form[ 'password' ];
$first_name = $form[ 'first_name' ];
$surname = $form[ 'surname' ];
$address = $form[ 'address' ];
$email = $form[ 'email' ];
// Sql
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password, first_name, surname, address, email )      VALUES ( :username, :password, :first_name, :surname, :address, :email )";

$result = $query->execute( array( ':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password, ':first_name'=>$first_name, ':surname'=>$surname, ':address'=>$address, ':email'=>$email ) );

if ( $result ){
   echo "Thank you. You have been registered";
} else {
   echo "Sorry, there has been a problem inserting your details.";
}
```

In addition I always, enable my error reporting as Tuga suggested. It never fails me.

Answer (score 0):

apart from the typo in the `passowrd` you should enable exceptions for PDO and use a try and catch statement to *catch* the exception. Also some other little changes, like structuring the PHP first and removing the odd re-assign of the POST superglobal.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $result = "Thanks for registering with us!";
    try{
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phpproject', 'root', 'pdt1848!');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,   password,  fname,  lname,  email)
                            VALUES(:username, :password, :fname, :lname, :email)";
        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':username'=>$_POST['username'],
                              ':password'=>$_POST['password'],
                              ':fname'=>$_POST['fname'],
                              ':lname'=>$_POST['lname'],
                              ':email'=>$_POST['email']));
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $result = 'Sorry, an error occurred while editing the database. Contact the guy who built this garbage.';
        //or use $e->getMessage(); for the real error
    }

    echo $result;

}
else{ ?>
<form name="registration" action="register.php" method="POST">
    <label for "username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
    <label for "password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br />
    <label for "fname">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="fname"/><br />
    <label for "lname">Last name: </label> 
    <input type="text" name="lname"/><br />
    <label for "email">Email: </label>
    <input type="text" name="email"/><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

**Also its a very bad idea to store plain-text passwords in your db.** ~ Read: [Best way to store password in database.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database/1054033)

### Edit,

Added some validation of your inputs to help you get started, hope it helps. not tested.

```
<?php
try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phpproject', 'root', 'pdt1848!');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    die('Sorry, an error occurred while editing the database. Contact the guy who built this garbage.');
    //or use $e->getMessage(); for the real error
}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    //create empty error array - to fill with errors if any
    $error = array();

    //validate username
    if(empty($_POST['username'])){
        $error['username'] = 'Enter a username';
    }elseif(strlen($_POST['username']) <= 2){
        $error['username'] = 'Username too short > 2 chars';
    }else{
        //check for existing user
        $sql = "SELECT 1 
                FROM `users` 
                WHERE username = :username";

        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username']));

        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($result)){
            $error['username'] = 'User already exists'; 
        }
    }

    //validate pass
    if(empty($_POST['password'])){
        $error['password'] = 'Please enter password';
    }elseif(strlen($_POST['password']) < 6){
        $error['password'] = 'Password too short, password should be 6 chars or longer';
    }

    //validate fname
    if(empty($_POST['fname'])){
        $error['fname'] = 'Please enter your first name';
    }

    //validate fname
    if(empty($_POST['lname'])){
        $error['lname'] = 'Please enter your last name';
    }


    //validate email
    if(empty($_POST['email'])){
        $error['email'] = 'Please enter your email';
    }else{
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $error['email'] = 'Please enter valid email';   
        }
    }

    //no errors detected so insert
    if(empty($error)){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,   password,  fname,  lname,  email)
                            VALUES(:username, :password, :fname, :lname, :email)";
        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':username'=>$_POST['username'],
                             ':password'=>$_POST['password'],
                             ':fname'=>$_POST['fname'],
                             ':lname'=>$_POST['lname'],
                             ':email'=>$_POST['email']));

        $result = 'Thanks for registering with us! <a href="login.php">Click here to login</a>';
    }else{
        $result = 'Please correct the errors';
    }

}?>

<?php echo isset($result) ? $result : null;?>

<form name="registration" action="register.php" method="POST">
    <label for "username">Username: <?php echo isset($error['username']) ? $error['username'] : null;?></label>
    <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
    <label for "password">Password: <?php echo isset($error['password']) ? $error['password'] : null;?></label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br />
    <label for "fname">First Name: <?php echo isset($error['fname']) ? $error['fname'] : null;?></label>
    <input type="text" name="fname"/><br />
    <label for "lname">Last name: <?php echo isset($error['lname']) ? $error['lname'] : null;?></label> 
    <input type="text" name="lname"/><br />
    <label for "email">Email: <?php echo isset($error['email']) ? $error['email'] : null;?></label>
    <input type="text" name="email"/><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: would you mind explaining that first line? "if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){"

Comment: @user3566526 its the proper way to check that the request method is POST, From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) 'REQUEST_METHOD' Which request method was used to access the page; i.e. 'GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT'.

Comment: you might want to add validation onto all of your POST inputs, in-case a user or bot just submits the form with blank values, causing you to get lots of empty rows inserted, also check for existing users before inserting

Comment: @carlgoodtoseeyou added an edited version with some validation, to help you get started. your welcome

Comment: I'm attempting to use phpass; I'm just a little unsure how to go about it.. I have the code, I just don't know where, or rather how to implement it. $password =$_POST['password'];
$hash_obj = new PasswordHash(8, false);
$hash = $hash_obj->HashPassword($password); 
$db_obj->insert_password($hash).

$db_obj->insert_password($hash)."

Comment: Ive never used it, generally you have a combination of 3 hashs to make the final hash thats not stored, a server hash key which is known only to the server, a user salt which is stored along with the users hash in the database, and the users hash, all 3 keys are salted together to make the final hash which is then checked. basically you need to hash the users password which is salted with an algo like sha512 or such, something strong not md5 or sha1.

Comment: Check out this login class, it pretty much explains in code what i mean. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515739/script-wont-log-in/11515866#11515866

Comment: Thanks for all your advice, I'm still trying to get a grip on try catch and PDO in general.